# IoC Container and global variable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I see advise from a lot of people teach not to use **global variable/singleton/static class** and move to use of a iOC container, for example, in PHP larvel framework, it is

```
App::bind('foo', function($app)
{
    return new FooBar;
});

$value = App::make('foo');
```

instead of

```
$value = new FooBar;
```

But to me, the `App::bind` itself is a static method and cannot be replaced easily.

So, can I say, the iOC (at least in PHP), is just remove the number of hard coded variable and minimized to `one`, which is the service locator, and it cannot be further reduced, right?

Answer (score 3):

`App::bind` is not a static method, this is it's signature:

```
public function bind($abstract, $concrete = null, $shared = false)
```

(found in `/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php`)

Laravel uses [Facades](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/facades), which, while they look like they are calling a method statically, actually instantiate an object under the hood and then call an instance method on that object.  While Laravel does use *some* static methods in it's models, the `App` object itself is actually a facade.  You can see a list of the built in facades if you look in `/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/`.

Comment: Yes but you are still binding your code to Laravel's. True dependency injection allows to decouple totally from architecture details (like containers).

Answer (score 2):

> So, can I say, the iOC (at least in PHP), is just remove the number of hard coded variable and minimized to one, which is the service locator, and it cannot be further reduced, right?

You are seeing this correctly, but you can actually reduce the number of hard coded variable to 0.

The problem here is not `App::bind()` because it's configuration. Configuration has to be coupled to some kind of system because that's where you set all the details. That's OK here.

But having `App::make()` all over your codebase is the problem. You want to write reusable code. You don't want your model to be coupled to Laravel for example. The fact of **calling the container** is called the **service locator pattern** (because you locate services with the IoC).

This is an anti-pattern, because, as I've said, you are coupling your code to the container.

On the other hand, there is the **dependency injection pattern** which is better. Dependencies are injected in your classes, but you don't care how. This is just pure PHP, completely decoupled from any container.

I invite you to read stuff on the subject, Laravel can actually be used with full dependency injection (no static calls to Facades). Here is an article on the subject: [Using Dependency Injection and IoC in Laravel 4 controllers](http://www.nathandavison.com/article/16/using-dependency-injection-and-ioc-in-laravel-4-controllers)

Answer (score 1):

Howard, I think the context you might be missing is why people say

> global variable/singleton/static class

are "bad".  The reasons you don't want global variables in your application is, relying on global state is going to lead to pain.  When you're modifying values that other parts of the program also have access to, it's likely two parts of a program are going to access that same variable and unexpected "bad" things will happen.  Singletons and static classes are often lumped in with global state, because they're globally available things.

So yes, your statment

> is just remove the number of hard coded variable and minimized to one, which is the service locator, and it cannot be further reduced, right

is accurate, but more than that a service container (if services are being created correctly) gives you global access to a thing-to-do-a-job, but is makes it hard/impossible to use that global thing-that-does-a-job to store global application state.